# Why doesn't Bash accept `&>&3`, i.e. redirecting stdout and stderr to file descriptor 3?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

Given the preamble, `foobar` function and invocations of it:

```
exec 3>/dev/null    
function foobar { echo foo; echo bar >&2; }
foobar >/dev/null
foobar 2>/dev/null
foobar &>/dev/null
foobar &>&3
```

Why doesn't the last simple command get executed by Bash? Instead Bash quits with:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there is no operator `&>&`.

There is an operator `&> word` that redirects both stdout and stderr to `word`.

There is an operator `[n]>& word` that duplicates fd `n` (default `1`) from fd `word`. As a special case, if `n` is empty, and `word` isn't a number, redirects both stdout and stderr to `word`.

But that's it. There isn't a special syntax for file descriptors which you can combine with operators. There are just the operators, which can interpret their operands as file descriptors or filenames. And there isn't a `&>&` operator which redirects both stdout and stderr, and interprets its right operand as a file descriptor.

Summary: There is no special syntax `&n` for file descriptors. The `&` belongs to the operator, not to the operand. There is no operator `&>&`.

Answer (score 2):

And why would it?  "... &>file" is just a syntactic sugar for "... >file 2>&1".  Nothing more.  If you want to make descriptor 2 point where 3 is pointing (/dev/null), you need to use "... 2>&3".